# Google Map Lite Mode moveCamera does not call setOnCameraIdleListener

Tags: google-maps, kotlin, android-maps-v2

Map shows correctly, then I check that the map is fully loaded before I do the *moveCamera* on it. The map then shows the correct area as defined by the bounds. But after the move, the *setOnCameraIdleListener* is never called as is expected. Here is the bit of code of question

```
map.setOnMapLoadedCallback(GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback {
    Log.e(tag, "setOnMapLoadedCallback")
    //set camera bounds
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, 100))
})

map.setOnCameraIdleListener {
    //create snapshot
    Log.e(tag, "setOnCameraIdleListener")
}
```

I am using lite mode for the map and according to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/lite) it looks like it should be supported but I couldn't find anything definite.

What may I be missing?

UPDATE:

Here is how I worked around this bug in the SDK.

Created a val defined as the callback.

```
private val snapshotReadyCallback : GoogleMap.SnapshotReadyCallback = GoogleMap.SnapshotReadyCallback {
    SaveSnapshot(it)
}
```

"it" is a bitmap of the map. You could do the saving directly in the callback but I call a function instead.

Within *setOnMapLoadedCallback* did the following

```
gmap?.setOnMapLoadedCallback {
    gmap?.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, 100))
    //2 seconds lag to ensure camera has had time to move
    //since camera move override doesnt work in setOnMapLoadedCallback
    handler.postDelayed({ // Do something after 2s = 2000ms
      gmap?.snapshot(snapshotReadyCallback)
    }, 2000)
}
```

Adding the delay to grab the snapshot allowed enough time for the camera to have moved already. It will then call the snapshotReadyCallback which will then call a function that does the actual saving.

Comment: Seeing the same behavior, did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @GrantKamin I did a work around. I did file a bug with Google about this but it's gone no where.